# How to use #pact maven plugin to verify a provider without port

Tags: java, maven, pact

Per https://docs.pact.io/implementation_guides/jvm/provider/maven/#2-define-the-pacts-between-your-consumers-and-providers
: Protocol, Host, and Port are required.

My spring boot rest app is on kubernetes, I have endpoint URL like https://fruitbasket.net/abc
If I don't specify the `port` tag, and run `mvn pact:verify`; test fail and it seems like `:8080` get appended during run time

```
https://fruitbasket.net/:8080/abc
```

Essentially, messing up the request endpoint.

*Please note:* I having fixed IP address and port isn't realistic.

How can I specify the provider host URL without port?

plugin config:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>au.com.dius.pact.provider</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <serviceProviders>
          <name>marketplace</name>
          <protocol>https</protocol>
          <host>fruitbasket.net</host>
        </serviceProvider>
      </serviceProviders>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

in my current project we use this config

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>au.com.dius.pact.provider</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven</artifactId>
   <version>4.2.0</version>
   <configuration>
      <pactBrokerUrl>https://mypactbroker</pactBrokerUrl>
      <trimSnapshot>true</trimSnapshot>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

with the annotation `@PactBroker(scheme = "https")`on the test class.

Comment: You need to initialize `ServiceProviders` in order to execute `mvn pact:verify`
and my question is around it's `port` tag 
`Execution default-cli of goal au.com.dius.pact.provider:maven:4.1.13:verify failed: lateinit property serviceProviders has not been initialized ` .

Comment: ^^ Any suggestions/ recommendations

Answer (score 1):

The pom.xml is not correct. You are missing to open serviceProvider tag